# Group table view with multiple text fields

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a group table view with 10 sections, each section has one cell, and each cell has a text field inside.

When user tap on a text field I scroll its parent cell to bottom, so that it will be exactly above the keyboard.

Every text field has a "Next" return key, so when user tap it the next text field (in the cell below) should be first responder.

The problem is:
Suppose user tap on a text field of cell at index 5, this will make the keyboard pop up and the tableview will scroll so this cell will be right above the keyboard.
Now user press the next button..
What I want to happen is to make the text field of cell at index 6 become the first responder.
But how do I get this text field??
If I try to get the cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I'll get nil, because the cell is invisible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions come to mind:

1) you don't have many cells, so don't recycle them, create them when you startup and put them in an array where you can easily get them, Then, when the tablview asks for cells, you pull them out of your array.

When you want to go to next, you simultaneously tell the tableview to scroll to such and such a location or cell, and you pull the cell out of the array, add it to your view with some offscreen frame so it cannot be seen, and make the textField the first responder (to keep the keyboard up). when the tableView asks for the cell, you MAY need to reset the frame, or both reset the frame and remove it from the view. If you find you need to do this you MAY need to make it the first responder again soon (dispatch a block to the main queue so that the text field never resigns first responder.

2) Similarly, when you want to make a cell's textField the first responder, and its contained in the visible cells, then you can just scroll and make it the first responder. If its not in the visibleCells, create a cell, add it to the view as above, do the first responder stuff as above, and when you are asked for THAT cell's index, supply that cell, possibly resetting the frame.

I've used offscreen textFields to play tricks with the keyboard (to keep it up, to get it up, etc - so I know that works). What's less certain to me are the tricks with the textField being in the view or not.

This makes me think of a 3rd way. You put a UITextField offscreen in the view. When you want to switch, and the cell is not yet visible (that is, created), you tell the offscreen textField to be firstReponder, then track the tableView scrolling, and when it ends the textField you WANT s first responder is now visible, so you can transfer (ie set) firstResponder on it, keeping the keyboard up.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how you create your rows but you need to consider, that UITableView recycles the cells. That means that the text field could be theoretically the same as before, just the content changes.

So all you need to do is make sure you know the textfield that is positioned right above the keyboard. I would not be surprised if this will be created when the view enters and never actually changes.

Again, the table recycles the cells and their content holders only filling in the corresponding data for the row as you provide it.

If you post your code that creates and recycles the cells I could be more specific.